# Can this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 ColumnA   ColumnB
    1         0
    2         0
    2         1
    2         2
    3         0
    3         0
```

Can this query below be optimized?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE ColumnA NOT IN (SELECT ColumnA 
                         FROM TABLE
                        WHERE ColumnB = 2)
   AND ColumnB = 0
```

This should return 1 and 3.

I want to select distinct values from ColumnA, but only if there is a value in ColumnB equal to 0... and there is no value in ColumnB equal to 2.  Is there a more optimal way to rewrite this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I say this is as optimal as it'll get. You may want to look at indexes if this query is giving you trouble.

Comment: Yep, I'd agree with John: just make sure you index column B.

Comment: Is it a bottleneck? ie. do you have a performance problem and have measured your code and figured out that this query is the topmost contented for the cause of the performance problem? If not, then I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: See: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ColumnA 
  FROM TABLE a 
 WHERE a.CoulumnB = 0 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                     FROM TABLE b 
                    WHERE b.ColumnA = a.ColumnA 
                      AND b.ColumnB = 2)
```

Comment: Whether this is better, worse, or exactly the same as the original poster depends on the RDBMS and particular data. Definitely worth an experiment.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: See: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Comment: @OMG Ponies. Very interesting. On Postgresql `NOT IN` used to be the consistently slowest, although I believe that is no longer so.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: This tagged Oracle, but here's a link for the same stuff on PostgreSQL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Comment: @OMG Ponies: checked with PG 9.0. My home installation is a joke (old and underpowered laptop), and the `NOT IN` was 100x slower than the other two [329s to ~3s], which were done by a Hash Anti-Join.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: You'd have to take that up with the author, but I believe the article was done using 8.4

Answer (score 1):

Having a `not in` can be bad for performance. You could try grouping instead, and count the number of zeroes and twos in each group:

```
select
  ColumnA,
  sum(case ColumnB when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Zeroes,
  sum(case ColumnB when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Twos
from TABLE
group by ColumnA
having Zeroes > 0 and Twos = 0
```

I'm not sure if this is more efficient without checking the execution plans, but as it's more straightforward it may very well be.

Also, this is SQL Server syntax, so it might need some tweaking to run in Oracle.

Comment: Interesting approach, but `NOT IN` isn't that bad: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Comment: For me, this query is easier to read and match up with the original question, so +1 for that.  The downside is that it always hits the entire table, where other methods could be looking at a much smaller set of data based on the restrictions on ColumnB.  It really depends on the nature of the data and what the execution plans look like.

Comment: @Cheran S: Yes, it depends on how common the 0 and 2 values are in ColumnB. If those are the most common values, there is no way to avoid reading most of the table, but if only a small part of the records have those values, it's more efficient to single out those records.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is about as good as it gets.  Only way really to get faster is to make an indexed view of this query and use it as your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid NOT IN whenever possible

maybe this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM TABLE t
LEFT JOIN TABLE z ON t.ColumnA=z.ColumnA AND z.ColumnB=2 
WHERE t.ColumnB=0 AND z.ColumnA IS NULL
```

Comment: There's no difference - see: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

Is this a real world example? Will the table only ever have this very small number of rows? If so, then you aren't really likely to be able to optimise it much further, the table is just too small. Having said that, "not in" wont scale very well, you'd be better of to use "not exists".

Comment: As OMG Ponies has mentioned, I believe recent versions of the optimizer will rewrite NOT IN and NOT EXISTS as the same execution plan.